# If $h(v) \ne 0$ is valid over a compact set, then its sign is constant (either positive or negative)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Assume that $h(v) \ne 0$ for all $v \in V$, with $V$ compact and the map $h:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ is of class $C^1$.

Can we prove that: there is $\alpha>0$ such that $h(v) \geq \alpha$, for all $v \in V$ or $h(v) \leq -\alpha$ for all $v \in V$?

My idea is that: since $V$ is compact, so we can have $\min_{v\in V} h(v)= h(v^*) >0$ or  $\max_{v\in V} h(v)= h(v') <0$ for some $v^*, v'\in V$.

Comment: You need $V$ connected. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space

Comment: Indeed, if $V$ is not assumed to be connected, then it could be, for example, just two points. And there’s nothing preventing $h$ to be positive at one point but negative at the other.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for your answer. Therefore, when assuming that $V$ is connected, the assertion given above/idea f=of proof become correct?

Comment: Yes, of course. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Theorems